# A more efficient mob spawning algorithm

Tags: java, game-engine

this is my method to find a free space in my world. The world consists of blocks which are collidable and non collidable. I do not want mobs to spawn in collidable blocks as they cannot move. However, this method does not work correctly, how can I improve it to make the code actually spawn all mobs in free spaces?

All of the blocks are randomly generated.

```
public int findSpawnX(int limit) {
    int xx = random.nextInt(limit) / 16; //find a random x coordinate and divide it by 16 to snap it to a block.

    if (getBlock(xx, 0).solid()) findSpawnX(limit); //check if xx is at a solid block, if so then redo the method.
    return xx; // if it is not solid then return the coordinate.
}
```

This code works. But some mobs spawn in blocks. I want all of the randomly spawned mobs to not spawn in solid blocks.

Comment: Are you worried about efficiency or that it works?  It seems to me we should figure out why it doesn't work first, and we almost certainly don't have enough information for that.

Comment: The original code works. However, there is the often exception in 1 or 2 mobs being spawned in a solid block. I want to make this 100% accurate, since all of the terrain is randomly generated.

Comment: Check out my edit.  The problem was that you were returning your original xx value, despite your recursion.  My edit fixes your code from a basic functional standpoint.  Simply leaving the question about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you never change the value of `xx` when the method is called again, so it always stays as the first value. Changing `if (getBlock(xx, 0).solid()) findSpawnX(limit);` to 
`if (getBlock(xx, 0).solid()) xx = findSpawnX(limit);` will work.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before however, it gives me a StackOverflowError.

Comment: This is certainly not the cause of your stackOverFlow error.  This answer is just fixing the issue with your code, which is that it will inevitably only work if your first call finds the solution, otherwise you call recursively, simply to return the first value you found, which if you called recursively, is a junk value you did not want.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your function recursively on failing is not good coding (apart from [the problem with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062347/1711796)). Instead go for the iterative approach:

```
public int findSpawnX(int limit) {
    int xx;
    do
    {
       xx = random.nextInt(limit) / 16;
    }
    while (getBlock(xx, 0).solid());
    return xx;
}
```

Comment: This method also works, but if you're unlucky, continually finding a random number could lead to many more searches than necessary.  I would say this answer vs mine is dependant on the % chance of finding a blocked square.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is get your random coordinate, and then use this as a seed for your position.  Assuming the position is valid(not blocked) return it.  Otherwise expand in a spiral, checking blocks in a circular spiral pattern, iteratively.  In 2-d space you could check blocks in this order:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXX543XXX
XXXX612XXX
XXXX789XXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

Spiraling out until you find an empty block, with a similar relative position in your game world.  Again, this is assuming that your general methodology works, and the only issue with it was that if it found a blocked coordinate, it did no handling of this situation.  An assumption I highly recommend you test thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand *"and divide it by 16 to snap it to a block."* the major inefficiency in your code is the unnecessary recursive call (where your method calls itself). This can go on for a long time, a method calling itself, calling itself, then calling itself...

Use a loop instead:

```
 while(getBlock(xx, 0).solid()) {
     xx = random.nextInt(limit) / 16;
 }
```

Comment: All components within the map are composed of 16*16 pixel blocks. I am calculating everything in terms of pixels, then converting them in terms of blocks for the game.

Comment: And this whilst this is a good solution. Mobs still spawn within the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine there's an issue with either your solid method or the getBlock method, if iterating along x (assuming there's at least 1 free block/tile) doesn't work then it has to be an error in how you retrieve the block, or it's an issue with solid.

```
//may go into an infinite loop if all blocks along x are solid
//could be solved quite inefficiently by buffering the block positions
//in an array and also using this to prevent checking the same block twice
//or instead, you could iterate along x and check if there's a non-solid
//block and return its position.
//Assuming your levels are procedurally generated, this should be fine.
public int findSpawnX(int limit) {
    int xx = random.nextInt(limit) / blockWidth;
    while(getBlock(xx, 0).solid()) {
        xx = random.nextInt(limit) / blockWidth;
    }
    return xx;
}
```

My opinion on the matter is that you (assuming everything else works as should) should implement a findSpawn / trySpawn procedure that uses the initial position (x, y) as seed to iterate in some pattern to more efficiently find a spawn position in the level. Going along both axes and not just one.

Another note: What I often see is getBlock / getTile procedures doing the divisions as to reduce the amount of code in other parts of the source and to increase readability.. you might want to keep that in mind.

Hope that helps to some extent!